# Using the RabbitMQ HTTP API with Go

Tags: go, rabbitmq

I am using RabbitMQ HTTP API to consume message from a queue. Here is the code I used for consuming messages.

```
    const (
    RabbitMQAPI = "https://url"
    VHOST       = "cpTestHost"
    EXCHANGE    = "pytest"
    VHOSTAPI    = "%s/api/vhosts/%s"
    PUBLISHAPI  = "%s/api/exchanges/%s/%s/publish"
    CONSUME     = "%s/api/queues/%s/%s/get"
)

type Payload struct {
    Count    int    `json:"count"`
    Ackmode  string `json:"ackmode"`
    Encoding string `json:"encoding"`
    Truncate int    `json:"truncate"`
}
type Message struct {
    PayloadBytes    int           `json:"payload_bytes"`
    Redelivered     bool          `json:"redelivered"`
    Exchange        string        `json:"exchange"`
    RoutingKey      string        `json:"routing_key"`
    MessageCount    int           `json:"message_count"`
    Properties      []interface{} `json:"properties"`
    Payload         string        `json:"payload"`
    PayloadEncoding string        `json:"payload_encoding"`
}

func failOnError(err error, msg string) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("%s: %s", msg, err)
    }
}

func main() {
    recAPI()
}

func basicAuth(username, password string) string {
    auth := username + ":" + password
    return base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte(auth))
}
func recAPI() {
    payload := Payload{
        Count:    5,
        Ackmode:  "ack_requeue_true",
        Encoding: "auto",
        Truncate: 50000,
    }
    pm, err := json.Marshal(payload)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Unmarshalling Error -> %s is %v", pm, err.Error())

    }
    client := &http.Client{}
    fmt.Printf("URL ---> %s\n", fmt.Sprintf(CONSUME, RabbitMQAPI, VHOST, EXCHANGE))
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", fmt.Sprintf(CONSUME, RabbitMQAPI, VHOST, EXCHANGE), bytes.NewBuffer(pm))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error %v", err)
    }
    req.Header.Add("Authorization", "Basic "+basicAuth("user", "pwd"))
    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
    resp2, err := client.Do(req)
    var dat Message
    recordsBodyResp := bufio.NewScanner(resp2.Body)
    fmt.Println(recordsBodyResp.Text())
    if err := json.Unmarshal(recordsBodyResp.Bytes(), &dat); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Response from Receiving a Message is %v\n", dat)
}
```

The sender code works as expected, but when I try to consume a message, it always returns blank response.
I would like to understand if the above code is correct and is consuming from RabbitMQ via their REST API reliable?

Comment: the code seems okay at first sight. are you sure that the queue you consume from is correctly bound to the exchange?

Comment: another thing, the queue url that you build with fmt.Sprintf contains the exchange name in it. Is the queue name actually the same as the exchange?

Comment: ah well.. you are also calling `Text()` on a `Scanner` without having `Scan`'ed anything first. To read the response body, use a `Reader`

Comment: The URL turns out to be https://<ip>/api/queues/cpTestHost/pytest/get and the queue works correctly, the same URL works with one of my Python script but it does not work with the Go one.

Comment: Yes you are right, it's the way I am reading the message is the problem. I have removed that and passed in io.ReadAll( ) and now able to read all the messages.Thanks for the hint :)

Comment: @AR7 can you share your findings as an answer?